# Why does calling focus() break my CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css-transitions

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05zTlD3lKwtQ1gtRkFJbUdzT0U/view?usp=sharing) html file shows a 3 panel layout. A css transition on the "left" property gives me a nice sliding effect when I change panels. It all works but, when I change panels, I want to place the focus on an input in the new panel. Can anyone tell me why the call to focus() breaks the css transition, and lands me half way between two panels? It only happens going forward. It works if I comment out the transition, and it works if I delay the call to focus() with a timeout.

The problem occurs in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

```js
var panelContainer;
var panels = new Array();
var numPanels;
var currentPanel = 0;

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

function init() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 10); //hiding the browser address bar in iPhone/Android

  panelContainer = document.getElementById("panelContainer");
  panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
  numPanels = panels.length;
  sizeResize();
}

function sizeResize() {
  panelContainer.style.width = (numPanels * window.innerWidth) + "px";
  panelContainer.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
  for (var i = 0; i < numPanels; i++) {
    panels[i].style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
    panels[i].style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
  }
  slide();
}
window.onresize = sizeResize;

function slide(panel) {
  if (panel != undefined)
    currentPanel = panel;
  panelContainer.style.left = -(window.innerWidth * currentPanel) + "px";
  if (panel >= 0) {
    panels[panel].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus(); //shows problem
    //window.setTimeout(function () { panels[panel].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus() }, 100);//no problem

  }
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#panelContainer {
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1000ms ease;
}

.panel {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="panelContainer">
    <div id="panel0" class="panel" style="background-color: #888;">
      panel zero
      <input id="btn0" class="focussable" type="button" onclick="slide(1);" value="forward" />
    </div>
    <div id="panel1" class="panel" style="background-color: #AAA;">
      panel 1
      <input id="btn1" class="focussable" type="button" onclick="slide(2);" value="forward" />
      <input type="button" onclick="slide(0);" value="back" />
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel" style="background-color: #CCC;">
      panel 2
      <input id="btn2" class="focussable" type="button" onclick="slide(1);" value="back" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a live demo for us to edit?

Comment: For whatever reason, my attempt to reproduce this as a jsfiddle didn't work. You can save the code locally, and open it in a browser from your file system. I don't have a web facing server handy sorry.

Comment: This is not a total answer, but maybe useful... The browsers have rules for scrolling the active element into view. These rules have precedence over whatever behaviour you might try to script. In the above example, tabbing also caused me problems. The workaround for the moment is to manage focus at all times. Something on the page must always be focussed, and calls to focus() are made inside setTimeout() so transitions have a chance to complete.

Comment: Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/c1ho6k1q/) showing the issue.

Comment: Thank you that shows the issue perfectly. I've changed the timeout to 300ms, and now the timeout version shows the desired behaviour. Tis a tricky one.

Comment: Run into this too.. This is so strange.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @user1585345 correctly stated a browser immediately scrolls to the focused element in order to bring it inside the current view, and not a px further!

What happens here is the following: you change the relative position of your element, but immediately you change focus, since the focused elements when the event fires is not visible  the content also *scrolls* (ending the animation abruptly).

You should explicitly fire your focus only when the animation is complete, so that the browser recognise that no scrolling is necessary.

One solution is (suggested by [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4840165/mark))

> there are two event listeners 'ontransitionend' and 'onanimationend'
> you can add an event for and then fire your focus() function

Comment: This just saved me from going mad 3 years later. It's a pain though because it means you have to use timeouts and hope if you use CSS transitions, or switch to scripted animations so you know when they finish.

Comment: false, there are two event listeners 'ontransitionend' and 'onanimationend' you can add an event for and then fire your focus() function.

Comment: That's one way to achieve what I suggest. I don't see how this makes my answer false. Can you elaborate so we can fix the answer with more details?

Comment: MARK THANK YOU!!!  i needed to learn ontransitionend!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, `focus()` scrolls to the element and visually breaks any transition mid-flow.

If you didn't want to rely on listeners, and depending on your requirements, you could use the `preventScroll: true` flag when calling the `focus()` method.

```js
input.focus({ preventScroll: true })
```

See the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus#focus_with_and_without_scrolling) and also [check browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus#browser_compatibility). Not all browsers support this but many of them do.